# Ansible: Create Config based on File List

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-template

I'm a little confused on how to make this work and need a better understanding in terms of the ansible side of getting the following done:

I have 500 images and I need to generate a default json config based on the image names. For example:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
etc etc
```

From that list, I need to generate the following:

```
1.json
2.json
3.json
etc etc
```

When it's all said and done the directory should have 500 images and 500 json files. I would also like to have that json file as a j2 template so I can pre define some information in the json file based on the project in a group_var.

I know I can do the following to copy the template doing this:

```
- name: Copy JSON Configuration
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: sample.json.j2
    dest: /path/to/directory
```

I'm just lost in the part to generate the list of the json files based on the image list. I have googled some stuff that is maybe the same but what I have found seem way beyond what I needed to get done or I'm not simply understanding it correctly. Thank you for any and all help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, given the tree

```sh
shell> tree test-616
test-616
├── 1.jpg
├── 2.jpg
└── 3.jpg
```

and the template

```yaml
shell> cat sample.json.j2
{{ item }}
```

Find the files and iterate the paths

```yaml
    - find:
        path: test-616
      register: result
    - template:
        src: sample.json.j2
        dest: "{{ _item }}.json"
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
      vars:
        _item: "{{ item|splitext|first }}"
```

This will create the files

```sh
shell> tree test-616
test-616
├── 1.jpg
├── 1.json
├── 2.jpg
├── 2.json
├── 3.jpg
└── 3.json
```

Comment: Hello Vladimir thank you for your example and explanation. This is exactly what I needed and it worked perfectly.  The other examples I ran into seemed like so much but you broke it down in a way that was easy to understand thank you so much!